# Can't refer to a Panel in the code-behind by it's name given in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have my own VirtualizingWrapPanel, that derives VirtualizingPanel and IScrollInfo.

Here is the example of how it is used in xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="StationsListView"
             DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModelKey}"                 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <common:VirtualizingWrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource DestinationButtonStyle}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"
                               Style="{DynamicResource DestinationStationTextBlockStyle}"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

If I give a name to the VirtualizingWrapPanel by x:Name="vwp" then I can refer to the panel by it's name in a code-behind file, I mean, IntelliSense offers to refer to the panel. But the compilation fails. The compiler complains that it can't resolve the name I gave to the panel in xaml.

I solved this issue by searching the panel in the object graph inside ContendRendered event. But it seems like a dirty hack.

How can I overcome the issue by using the Name property (somehow)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates in WPF are not like regular XAML object trees. When you say `<Window/>` in your XAML, it means "create an instance of the `Window` class". When you say `<DataTemplate><Window/></DataTemplate>` it means "create an instance of the `DataTemplate` class that knows how to create a window" (`ItemsPanelTemplate` is no different). In that sense your `VirtualizingWrapPanel` instance shall begin existing only once the template object tree is instantiated - but that can happen multiple times! If it were bound to an instance field in your code-behind, then which of its instantiations should be assigned to it?

More generally, templates define [a namescope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx). Names within a namescope must be unique and lookup using FrameworkElement.FindName() works only for the namescope in which the respective FrameworkElement has been instantiated. A template can be instantiated multiple times, and each instantiation defines a separate namescope in which you can look for named objects.

Searching in the object tree is a good general way to deal with this situation. Another would be to add a behavior to the panel (i.e. an attached property that implements the necessary logic in its PropertyChanged handler). The attached property logic would then be executed every time this template is executed.

Comment: Why the instantiating of the template object tree can occure multimple times? By the way, an excellent answer, thank you!

Comment: Multiple calls to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.loadcontent.aspx , e.g. `ItemsControl` will call LoadContent on its `ItemTemplate` multiple times - once for each item in it.